# Uninstalling all depends packages as long it isn't depended by another package

Tags: apt

I want to uninstall `packageA` as well as all the other packages packageA depended on but not the packages who still have dependencies.

```
$ apt-cache depends packageA
packageA
  Depends: packageB
  Depends: packageC

$ apt-cache depends packageD
  Depends: packageC

$ apt-cache rdepends packageB
  Reverse Depends:
    packageA

$ apt-cache rdepends packageC
  Reverse Depends:
    packageA
    packageD
```

`packageA`, `packageB`, `packageC` and `packageD` are currently installed. I want to uninstall `packageA`. Since `packageB` is the only package that depended on `packageA` I want to uninstall that too. `packageC` should still be installed since `packageD` needs it. I don't want to uninstall `packageD`.

I know there is `apt autoremove`. However I do not wish to use `apt autoremove` since there are some "unused" packages which are actually used. Due to the sheer amount however I cannot tell which unused packages those are and I don't wish to install all the unused packages.
The dependencies is being fixed but it is taking time. For now I need a workaround solution.

Answer (score 0):

Aptitude should do this for you. If `packageB` is marked as automatically installed,

```
aptitude remove packageA
```

will remove `packageA` and `packageB`. Since `packageC` is still required by another package, it won’t be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find another program like autoremove. I've used autoremove and it has never broken my system. Maybe this is something to consider? Create a backup list of all installed packages

sudo cp -a /etc/apt/sources.list{,.bak} && sudo apt install apt-clone -y && mkdir ~/mypackages && sudo apt-clone clone ~/mypackages

Now you can run *sudo apt autoremove* and if you run into any issues just restore

```
sudo apt-clone restore apt-clone-state-ubuntuserver.tar.gz
```